# Changing advanced power settings windows 7 (batch / powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I already have this which can change the basic settings of the current power plan, but I need to change advanced power setting such as what closing the lid does and what the power button does.

```
POWERCFG -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 15
POWERCFG -CHANGE -monitor-timeout-dc 15
POWERCFG -CHANGE -standby-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG -CHANGE -standby-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG -CHANGE -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG -CHANGE -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it once for AC and once for DC.

First Type

```
powercfg getactivescheme
```

Then (For *HP High Performance* Scheme)

```
powercfg query 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

Which tells us the subgroup and setting GUID.

For lid close

```
  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936  (Lid close action)
      GUID Alias: LIDACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
```

Then to change AC to 1  - sleep from table above

```
powercfg setacvalueindex 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1
```

Repeat for DC

```
powercfg setdcvalueindex 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1
```